# java tool to check naming convention

Tags: java, conventions

from eclipse, I'm using Junit4 to write some java tests to control the GUI
I'm looking for a tool open source that check naming conventions : upper case,lower case int he case of variables, functions ,...etc
what do you recommend me as a practical tool ?

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) should meet your needs and can be had via an [Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).

Comment: how can I activate it, is it available within ecplise IDE ?

Comment: @lola Check out the second link, it shows you how to add it as a plugin.

Comment: AAron, I follow steps defined in the link you send and I restart ecplise, then show Checkstyle view, now how I can use it ? I tried to add a variable with a upper case but I don't have any message ?

Comment: @lola See http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/basic_setup_project.html and http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/basic_creating_config.html

Comment: Aaron, I followed steps as described , but how to activate Checkstyle to test this, I declare a variable with upper case and run test but in the problems view, no reference to naming conventions ??

Comment: I followed steps as described , but how to activate Checkstyle to test this, I declare a variable with upper case and run test but in the problems view, no reference to naming conventions ??

Comment: @lola Perhaps you should open a new question, focused on how to leverage Checkstyle.

Answer (score 0):

checkstyle. Most likely there is a plugin for your IDE. There is also a plugin for jenkins/hudson

Comment: Jens, when I click help-->install software then add checkstyle link , I got : no item selected

Comment: Eclipse I guess? Did you followed these instructions? http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html